# Remove rows with all NA values after groupby r

Tags: r, group-by, na

I want to remove rows which has all NAs after using group_by. here is a sample dataset:

```
df=data.frame(Col1=c("B","B","C","D",
                      "P1","P2","P3")
               ,Col2=c(NA,8,NA,9,10,8,9)
               ,Col3=c(NA,7,6,8,NA,7,8)
               ,Col4=c(NA,NA,7,7,NA,7,7))
```

i want to groupby Col1 and remove rows if column values are all NA.
So the desired output is:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 8 | 7 | NA |
| C | NA | 6 | 7 |
| D | 9 | 8 | 7 |
| P1 | 10 | NA | NA |
| P2 | 8 | 7 | 7 |
| P3 | 9 | 8 | 7 |

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: after grouping by Col1, what summary stat you want to apply? I think this is missing before remove NA.

Comment: Why does your expected output omit the last row (`P3,9,8,7`, no `NA`s)?

Comment: sorry my mistake! the last row should be there. edited the table to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `group_by`, you can use `if_any`.

```r
library(dplyr)
filter(df, if_any(-Col1, ~ !is.na(.)))
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
# 1    B    8    7   NA
# 2    C   NA    6    7
# 3    D    9    8    7
# 4   P1   10   NA   NA
# 5   P2    8    7    7
# 6   P3    9    8    7
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! this works perfect! I was able to edit it to use with group_by. Thanks! look for my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for group-by, keep only rows where there is at least 1 non-na column, excluding *Col1*:

```
df[ rowSums(!is.na(df[, -1])) > 0, ]
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
# 2    B    8    7   NA
# 3    C   NA    6    7
# 4    D    9    8    7
# 5   P1   10   NA   NA
# 6   P2    8    7    7
# 7   P3    9    8    7
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of r2evans answer, I was able to remove NAs after grouping by using group_by. Thanks everyone who answered.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Col1) %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~ !is.na(.)))

 Col1   Col2  Col3  Col4  
 B         8     7    NA
 C        NA     6     7
 D         9     8     7
 P1       10    NA    NA
 P2        8     7     7
 P3        9     8     7
```